# Invoking custom cmdlet from script block in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, start-job

I'm very new to PowerShell. I wrote a cmdlet which works fine. However, when I try and invoke it inside a  job...

```
. .\MyCmdlet.ps1 # Dot Source
$GetProcesssJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  MyCmdlet
} -Credential $specialCredentials
```

...I get the error that it's *"not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `*-Job` cmdlets start a new runspace so things you load in your existing session do not exist there.  Dot-source your `MyCmdlet` script in the scriptblock for `Start-Job`

Comment: I had actually tried that and it didn't work. I now realize that's because the credentials I was using in $specialCredentials didn't have access to the file MyCmdlet.ps1!

Comment: You might be able to use `-InitializationScript` - I'm unsure what context that gets run in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems were two-fold. As TheIncorrigible1 pointed out, I needed to put the dot-sourcing inside the ScriptBlock. However, I had tried that previously and it didn't work. I now realize that's because the credentials I was using in $specialCredentials didn't have access privileges to the file MyCmdlet.ps1!